# そして after して, is it natural?

Tags: grammar

> 描いたものを保存して、予約投稿**して、そして**PCを落とした。

The conjunction そして here means **and then**, but the conjunction して before it can also mean **and then**, isn’t it repeated and clumsy?

To me it sounds like:予約投稿した後、そしてPCを落とした, which is very clumsy.

Answer (score 3):

A te-form is just a mild "and". It's natural to combine a te-form and そして (or それから, その後に) if you want to emphasize the order, like you say "..., and then ..." or "..., and after that, ..." in English.

On the other hand, it sounds strange to use both -した後 and そして at the same time ("after I posted, and then" sounds strange in English, too).